# In C# how to remove items in an array after a certain length?

Tags: c#, collections

If i have an array of objects and I want to remove all items after a certain length

for example if the startlength of the array is 10 and I want to only keep the first 5 items in the array and remove everything after that.  NOTE: The array might be less than 5 which would do nothing.

```
  int startLength = 10;
  int maxLength = 5;
  List<MYObject> myList = CreateListofObjects(startLength);
```

I want something like "RemoveAfter" where "RemoveAfter" would do something like this:

```
  myList = myList.RemoveAfter(maxLength);

  Assert.IsTrue(myList.Count() ==5);
```

Comment: Side note: your title says "array", but you want to manipulate a `List`. Also you did not specify if you need to keep List or new instance is ok - so you have 2 answers covering both choices (Mitch Wheat's and  Serdalis', +1 each).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
myList = myList.Take(maxLength).ToList();
```

[Note: this creates a new list, which we assign to the original list placeholder (myList), rather than altering the original list in place. ]

Comment: Just note that this isn't mutating the existing collection, it's creating a new sequence/collection.

Answer (score 2):

`Take` and `ToList` may work (also it will create new list)

```
 myList = myList.Take(maxLength).ToList();
```

And if you need to keep the list - [RemoveRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx) is there too:

```
 myList.RemoveRange(maxLength, myList.Count - maxLenght);
```

Note: make sure samples work for cases when list have less items than maxLength.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [`RemoveRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y33yd2b5.aspx)

Example:

```
if(myList.Count() > maxLength) {
    myList.RemoveRange(maxLength, (mylist.Count()-maxLength));
}
```

Comment: This will throw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException if the list is too short.

Comment: @Tim of course, just make sure that the list is smaller than the maxLength.